# Access viewbag values from view (.cshtml)

Tags: c#, asp.net, multidimensional-array, viewbag, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi Can someone help me how to access viewbag values from my view (.cshtml)
Here is my sample

```
var appointments = new[,] { { "4/1/2013", "B'day" }, { "4/2/2013", "Appointment with abc" } };
ViewBag.Appointments = appointments;
```

Now I want to access ViewBag.Appointments values from my .cshtml file.

Any idea?

Comment: where do you want access  these value in controller?

Comment: Have you tried anything, you can read from Viewbag just as you read from a 2D array.

Comment: @{    
    var appointments = ViewBag.Appointments;
}

Comment: Yes I tried.. Just I wanted to display the total length of array like ViewBag.Appointments.length and it is not giving any results. And when I read like ViewBag.Appointments[0,0] it is showing results. But I wanted to loop through it. How can I?

Answer (score 8):

This is how you are going to access the data in your ViewBag. Remember ViewBag data is normally dynamic and can only be accessed at runtime.

```
ViewBag.Appointments = appointments;
```

After you've set ViewBag data in the controller, retrieve it in your view as shown below.

```
@{
    var appointments = ViewBag.Appointments;
}
```

Then you can loop through the results to get the individual items using a foreach loop.

```
@foreach(var appointment in appointments)
{
    <p>@appointment.value</p>
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: should be @item.value, and it is ViewBag, the name is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

To loop through this array and "print it" in cshtml use following code:

```
@foreach(var appointement in ViewBag.Appointments)
{
   <span>@appointement[0]</span>
   <span>@appointement[1]</span>
}
```

Comment: I'm getting object reference error. I wanted to access this viewbag value in my function. Here is my code, <script> function getvalues() { -- here I want to loop viewbag value -- } </sctipt> Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To print all the values of the viewbag in a view in a single column use the following

```
@{
    for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Appointments.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ViewBag.Appointments.GetLength(1); j++)
        { 
           <B>  @ViewBag.Appointments[i, j] </B> <br />
        }
    }    
}
```

To print all the values of the viewbag in a view as key value pairs then use the following

```
@{
    for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Appointments.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
           <B>  Key= @ViewBag.Appointments[i, 0], Value= @ViewBag.Appointments[i, 1] </B> <br />
    }    
}
```

**EDIT** - As requested in Comment below

You can have a look at this [NGON](https://github.com/brooklynDev/NGon) project on GIT Hub. **Note**: on the same page, you will find a detailed tutorial.

A small extract from the help page to get you started.

In your controller, you can add any value to the dynamic NGon property of the ViewBag:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.NGon.Appointments= new[,] { { "4/1/2013", "B'day" }, { "4/2/2013", "Appointment with abc" } };
        return View();
    }
}
```

Then in you script function, you can use it as shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

          var appointments= ngon.Appointments;
          // You logic will come here  
    }); </script>
```

Try it out, it should work.

Comment: Hi Romulus, thanks for your reply. I wanted to loop these values in my function. And it is not accepting. Can you help me how to use this code in below sample? <script> function getvalues() { -- here I want to loop viewbag value -- } </sctipt>